# How to randomize address space at runtime for benchmarking purposes

Tags: performance, performance-testing, benchmarking, aslr

I'm looking for a mechanism like ASLR for Linux in order to benchmark a *distributed* application while accounting for incidental layout changes. For background and motivation, see the [Stabilizer paper](https://people.cs.umass.edu/%7Eemery/pubs/stabilizer-asplos13.pdf).

The goal is to recreate the behavior of [Stabilizer](https://github.com/ccurtsinger/stabilizer), but in a distributed environment with complex deployment. (As far as I can tell, that project is no longer maintained and never made it past a prototype phase.) In particular, the randomization should take place (repeatedly) *at runtime* and without needing to invoke the program through a special binary or debugger. On the other hand, I assume full access to source code and the ability to *arbitrarily* change/recompile the system under test.

By "complex deployment", I mean that there may be different binaries running on different machines, possibly written in different languages. Think Java programs calling into JNI libraries (or other languages using FFI), "main" binaries communicating with sidecar services, etc. The key in all of these cases is that the native code (the target of randomization) is not manually invoked, but is somehow embedded by another program.

I'm only concerned about the *randomization* aspect (i.e., assume that metrics collection/reporting is handled externally). It's fine if the solution is system-specific (e.g., only runs on Linux or with C++ libraries), but ideally it would be a general pattern that can be applied "anywhere", regardless of the compiler/toolchain/OS.

---

Side note: layout issues are *less* of a concern on larger systems thanks to the extra sources of random noise (network, CPU temperatures/throttling, IPC overheads, etc). However, in many cases, distributed applications are deployed on "identical" machines with *uniform* environments, so there's still plenty of room for correlated performance impacts. The goal is just to debias the process for decision making.

Comment: Modern Linux with PIE executables already does ASLR everything by default (stack and static code/data on execve, dynamic stuff on mmap, also the initial break is randomized for brk/sbrk, not contiguous with BSS).  But only at page granularity for static code/data, and some code-alignment effects are only wrt. 32-byte boundaries.  The initial stack pointer is randomized even with a page.

Comment: Page granularity is fine. The problem with Linux ASLR is that it only happens _once per process_.  I'd like it to happen periodically (better yet, randomly) at runtime. [Stabilizer](https://github.com/ccurtsinger/stabilizer) apparently rewrites the LLVM IR to randomize layout. I realize this is virtually impossible without some compiler trickery, but I'm having a hard time even doing this manually with code changes.

Comment: Changing the address of something requires you to rewrite any pointers holding the absolute address.  e.g. in the GOT.  That's vastly more complicated, and in general not possible for an unknown program, since you'd have to figure out which values were function pointers.  With source you could in theory distinguish pointers from integers that just happen to have the same value.  For data, the same problem of rewriting pointers applies.

Comment: Specifically, I would expect modern compilers to align data "efficiently" for the target architecture.  While it would be nice to do lower-level transforms like reordering branches to stress the branch predictor, I think it's unrealistic to do this without rewriting the machine code. I'm hoping that at least moving things around at a high level should help with unexpected changes due to cache packing.

Comment: For a few specific data items where you know what pointers to update, Linux `mremap(MREMAP_FIXED|MREMAP_MAYMOVE)` can move a mapping to a specified new virtual address.  But you have to be *sure* the new address isn't in use, because like MMAP_FIXED it will just clobber it.  It might be possible to do that for code if your program doesn't use function pointers.

Comment: wrt changing this for an "unknown" program: I'm not trying to make it that general. The idea is that I have access to the entire source code and can refactor everything (e.g., all function calls) to go through a randomizer. I have no idea what that should look like though, and I'm concerned that doing things this way would materially change _relative_ performance in a way to make results meaningless.

Comment: When I say "unknown", I mean "in general", rather than "by hand for this one program where you know how it uses pointers".  But ok, yeah, if you're *modifying* the source to introduce new levels of indirection or something (which would have a performance impact), then that could make it a lot easier.